# When to use Docker HEALTHCHECK vs livenessProbe / readinessProbe

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

The new ability to specify a HEALTHCHECK in a Dockerfile seems redundant with the Kubernetes probe directives. Any advice on what to use when?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you use Kubernetes, I'd suggest using only the Kubernetes liveness/readiness checks because Docker healthcheck [has not been integrated in the Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25829) as of now (release 1.12). This means that Kubernetes does not expose the check status in its api server, and the internal system components can not consume this information. Also, Kubernetes distinguishes [liveness from readiness checks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/), so that other components can react differently (e.g., restarting the container vs. removing the pod from the list of endpoints for a service), which the docker HEALTHCHECK currently does not provide.

Update: Since Kubernetes 1.8, the Docker HEALTHCHECK has been [disabled explicitly](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/50796) in Kubernetes.

Comment: Correct +1 The HEALTHCHECK feature was added by the Docker Inc. guys to provide Docker Swarm with a capability that already existed in Kubernetes (and Mesos/Marathon). As you've pointed they don't work exactly the same yet, so hard to see it adopted by Kubernetes in the short term

Answer (score 1):

**On Docker**

the HEALTHCHECK is basically a command running recurrently during the lifespan of the container. It is used to let the Docker daemon know about the health (i.e. state) of a container.

It is not always useful in general contexts.

**On Kubernetes**

the *liveness* probe is a command running recurrently during the lifespan of the container to let the Kubelet know the container is *alive* and *healthy* (i.e. up-and-running). The liveness probe is considered successful if the command returns 0, and failed when it returns a non-zero value. If the liveness probe fails, the container is killed and restarted by the Kubelet.

the *readiness* probe is a command running recurrently during the lifespan of the container to let the Kubelet know if a pod is *ready* to receive traffic (i.e. ready to work as expected) while it is already *alive*.

It is useful in the sense that it provides some level of resilience by detecting unhealthy containers that will be automatically restarted.